# twitter bootstrap / Inspinia modal bug when open more than one modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, inspinia

I need help using more than one modal with inspinia template, the problem is that I think there is a bug that break the z-index or something i'm not really sure, Images from the inspinia website

First Open one modal
[image: IMG1]

Then Open the second one with JQuery

> $("#myModal6").modal("show");

[image: IMG2]

Now close the small modal even if it is closed with jquery I get the same result

> $("#myModal6").modal("hide");

[image: IMG3]

And the first modal it is now stuck in the back
[image: IMG4]

---

Also I get the same error if I close one modal and open the second one with JQuery

First Open one modal
[image: IMG11]

Now I close and open the second one

> $("#myModal5").modal("hide");$("#myModal6").modal("show");

And get the modal stuck behind again

[image: IMG22]

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

The Inspinia site
http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.9.2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

on **inspinia.css** find `body.modal-open .animated {` and comment or delete this line `animation-fill-mode: initial;`

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD140.png)